# How to import rstudio installation in ubuntu

Tags: r

Good morning ,

I'm wanting **to migrate Rstudio installation** from my old laptop ( **windows 10** ) to my new one ( that uses **ubuntu** ).

For this purpose, I already copied **the windows **R folder**** ( Where the installed packages & versions are located , this folder is found at C: users/documents/ ).

I'm wondering where should I paste that file in ubuntu ? ( The ubuntu path where the windows R folder must be past ).

I hope my question is clear !

Thank you for help & advice !

Comment: If that's the path where your libraries/packages are installed, then you likely cannot do that. Installed packages occasionally have compiled code, which will not migrate. It is likely best to get a list of the directories (package names) and then in the new R do `install.packages(c("pkg1","pkg2",...))` (after verifying your `.libPaths()`, of course).

Comment: installed <- as.data.frame(installed.packages())

write.csv(installed, 'installed_previously.csv')

installedPreviously <- read.csv('installed_previously.csv')

baseR <- as.data.frame(installed.packages())

Comment: I already tried the code above : Does this will import all installed R versions ( with their packages without troubles ?

Comment: As to what that directory should be named on ubuntu: from `?.libPaths`, it says that *"By default ... R_LIBS_USER is set to directory 'R/`R.version$platform`-library/x.y' of the home directory on Unix-alike systems*". On ubuntu, `R.version$platform` likely resolves to `"x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"`, which means your dir should be `~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0` (or whichever major.minor R version you are using).

Comment: Include `install.packages(..., dependencies=TRUE)` and it should, yes. *However*, many packages require OS-packages be installed as well, and there is nothing you can do in R to do this for you. You may have none, or you may have some. Typically, a package-install that fails because of a missing OS library will include something like *"needs the `libgeos-dev` library"*, meaning you have to install that in the OS (not in R).